# How to hide post content/meta from everyone except the post author and admin

Tags: wp-query, user-roles

I'm trying to start myself off here but I can't get my head around it...
How can I hide an author's post content/meta from everyone except the post author and admin? This is my scenario...
Schools and teachers publish their own custom posts
Schools/Admin can see all teachers posts but only the teacher who published the post can see their post, other teachers can't see other teacher's posts.

Comment: if(get_current_user_id() == get_the_author_id() || current_user_can('do admin stuff') ) {//show post}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below code -

```
<?php
    global $current_user;


     if ((is_user_logged_in() && $current_user->ID == $post->post_author) || current_user_can( 'manage_options' ))  {
        echo 'my post';
    }
?>
```

Check below link also-

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can

Comment: so manage_options is a capability that only the admin and the post's author can do?

Comment: No, `manage_options` is **per default** only available to Administrators.